# Real number integer and fractional part separation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I had previously been certain that I was able to separate any real number into it's integer and fractional parts as follows, selecting any natural number greater than one for the base $p$:

$$d(x,p,j)=\Bigl\lfloor{x\,{p}^{\,j-  {\lfloor\ln_p(x)\rfloor}  -1}} \Bigr\rfloor-p\Bigl\lfloor{x\,{p}^{\,j-  {\lfloor\ln_p(x)\rfloor}  -2}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\ln_p(x)\rfloor+1}d(x,p,j)\,p^{\,\lfloor\ln_p(x)\rfloor+1-j}$$

$${\{x}\}=\sum_{j=\lfloor
\ln_p(x)\rfloor+2}^{\infty}d(x,p,j)\,p^{\,\lfloor
\ln_p(x)\rfloor+1-j}$$

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R$$

Addition 10/04/2019:

I want to make a special point of the case for $x=\pi$, as the above relation is true for all $p \gt 2$, for $p=2$, equating the above series to the fractional part of $\pi$ is false, and in fact converges to a **rational** number, $\frac{1}{8}$. I consider this fact to be significant, and would very much like to hear the thoughts of those individuals wiser than myself on the matter.

18/04/2019:

The updated version of maple agrees with my original evaluation for $p=2$,$x=\pi$. This is a little concerning to say the least.

However in using floating point approximations to various digits of precision, I have noticed that my computer calculates non zero values for many $(n,m,p)$ for the function:

$$f(n,m,p)=\Biggl|{\Bigl\{\frac{n}{m}}\Bigr\}-\sum_{j=\lfloor
\ln_p(\frac{n}{m})\rfloor+2}^{\infty}d\Bigl(\frac{n}{m},p,j\Bigr)\,p^{\,\lfloor
\ln_p(\frac{n}{m})\rfloor+1-j}\Biggr|$$

Because I initially was convinced that this must be an error of the software I am using to calculate floating point approximations, to confirm this, I raised the number digits of precision for which these approximations are made, however there remained a distribution of non zero values for the aforementioned function, some of which are unit fractions, others not.

So my question is, if this is indeed theoretical, what are equivalent predicates to $f(n,m,p) \not=0$ and $f(n,m,p)=0$ for the two equivalence classes that are elements of a partition of the set of all natural number pairs $(n,m)$ in terms of $p$?

Or to paraphrase, what common number properties do those number pairs for which $f(n,m,p) \not=0$ have?
[image]
[image]